# Pappus’s Theorem

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I'm reading through a history of math book and it says to

$(i)$ Interpret the figure as an illustration of Pappus’s theorem

$(ii)$ Write down a statement of the theorem corresponding to the figure, the conclusion of which is  that $P_1Q_3$ and $P_2Q_2$ are  parallel.

$(iii)$ Deduce the required equation from two other equations that express parallelism in the figure.

$(iv)$ Prove the theorem in the case where the two lines $P_1P_2$ and $Q_1Q_2$ do not meet at $O$, that is, when they too are parallel.

[image]

$(i)$ My book says that the usual statement of Pappus’s theorem is that

> the intersections of opposite sides of the hexagon are in a straight
>   line.

so I'm not sure how I would interpret the figure as an illustration of Pappus's theorem.

$(ii)$ I think the theorem statement would be that $P_1Q_3$ and $P_2Q_2$ are  parallel if and only if $$\frac{OP_1}{OP_2}=\frac{OQ_3}{OQ_2}$$

$(iii)$ In an attempt to prove this, I have assumed parallelity of $P_1Q_1$ and $P_3Q_2$ implying $\frac{OP_1}{OP_3}=\frac{OQ_1}{OQ_2}$

I have also assumed parallelity of $P_2Q_1$ and $P_3Q_3$ implying $\frac{OP_3}{OP_2}=\frac{OQ_3}{OQ_1}$

From here I went with a reverse proof:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{OQ_3}{OQ_2}
&=\frac{\frac{OP_3}{OP_2}OQ_1}{\frac{OP_3}{OP_1}OQ_1}\\\\
&=\frac{OP_1}{OP_2}\\\\
&\Rightarrow \frac{OP_1}{OP_2}=\frac{OQ_3}{OQ_2}
\end{align*}$$

$(iv)$ I'm not quite sure what it is asking or how to approach this one.

I'm looking for insight into $(i)$ and $(iv)$ and whether or not I did $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ correctly.

Answer (score 1):

*(i) My book says that the usual statement of Pappus’s theorem is that*
**the intersections of opposite sides of the hexagon are in a straight line.**
*so I’m not sure how I would interpret the ﬁgure as an illustration of Pappus's Theorem.*

[image]
What book are you reading?

If the two original lines are parallel then O is sitting out there on the line at infinity as well, so all four points (O and the three intersections of the opposite sides of the hexagon) are colinear.   Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It's called "Mathematics and its History" by John Stillwell.

Comment: This diagram definitely helps me visualize the problem [+1]

Comment: I've got the second edition in my hands as we type.  Diagram on page 142.  When a pair (or more) of opposite sides of your hexagon are parallel, postulate a point at infinity (so, now ALL lines intersect).  (iv) If the original two lines are parallel, then O is a point at infinity, too.

Comment: I have the third version so I'm not seeing the diagram

Comment: It's the same diagram you posted.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. And I must prove the same thing as in $(ii)$?

Comment: "And I must prove the same thing as in (ii)?"  You mean regarding the second diagram with the original lines parallel?  Yes, that's what he's asking.  Ought to be a way to do that synthetically right out of Euclid's "Elements," but I haven't thought about that.

Comment: Wouldn't the parallelism of $P_3Q_3$  and $P_2Q_1$ as well as the parallelism of $P_1Q_1$  and $P_3Q_2$ imply that $P_1Q_3$ is parallel to $P_2Q_2$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73687/discussion-between-estragon-and-remy).